# How to make a certain file openable with your own program?

Tags: java

I want to design a file based program that can manipulate files in java and I can do it fine in the program but I want to be able to right click on my file and select "Open with" so users know if my program can open their file.

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: i don't see how this is necessary as the code should be universal, it should just be able to run whatever code it needs when you right click and select open with?

Comment: but this is where the code comes from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/

Comment: I am sorry to say that may be this is not the right place to ask such questions. Please, have a tour on [what can you ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what can not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). StackExchange have other sites, you can visit there and read the title description to see that your question fits with any other site or not.  Thanks.

Comment: Weird because this is the Java forum...

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial by Oracle that describes how you can create a file association:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/fileassociation.html

I do not know how to do it by myself. I just thought the reference would be better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that.